# How to draw a fixed length curve?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Is it possible to draw a curve with some specified length between two points? I'm considering damped sines like [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tell%20me%20the%20arc%20length%20of%20y%20=%202%20%20sin%28%202%20%20PI%20/%2030%20%2a%20x%29%20from%20x%20=%200%20to%2030) or Bezier curves.

Comment: Do you mean, find a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0$ and $f(x_1)=y_1$? This is clearly possible (provided the specified length is at least as big as the distance between the points...). If you suggest a particular family of curves, then typically such a function will exist, though how easy it is to find depends on the specific family.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, like in the wolfram's example where the arc length is known. How do this in best way?

Answer (score 1):

You have three conditions to satisfy. The simplest SMOOTH one is a parable.

Answer (score 0):

If a specified length and specified endpoints are all you want, there are very many ways to do that. The easiest *smooth* way to proceed is probably to make it a circular arc ... whose center you'll need to find numerically (unless you happen to have an inverse sinc function available).

Comment: > whose center you'll need to find numerically -- I don't think so; it's a fairly simple calculation. Conceivably, it could be done without even using trig functions (though I haven't checked). I agree that a circular arc seems like the best choice, if end-points and arclength are the only constraints.

Comment: I was wrong. It looks like an inverse sine function is needed, but every math library provides this. I don't see where an inverse sinc function is needed. Typo, maybe?

Comment: @bubba: I've tried to derive the center in two different ways, and in each of them I end up needing to invert sinc or solve $\sin x = ax$. Perhaps you should write your calculation with just an arcsine as an answer?

Comment: it looks like you're correct. My apologies. I quit halfway through the calculations because I thought I could see the end result. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ok, you are right - this is the easy way. But if the length is very long then i have to stretch up those circular arcs. Thats why i come up with the damped sine or maybe beziers? But its rather complex and there are no equations which will help to simplify this task...